# Prove the proposition: there are infinitely many primes of the form 4k + 3, where k ≥ 0 is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Proposition 2. there are infinitely many primes of the form 4k + 3, where k ≥ 0 is an integer.

(a) Let n ∈ N. Suppose q1,q2,...,qn are positive integers such that for all 1 ≤ i ≤ n, each qi = 4ki + 3 
for some integer ki ≥ 0. In other words, each of the numbers q1,q2,...,qn are of the form 4k+3. Consider the number 
N = 4 (q1q2 · · · qn) − 1. Justify that N is also a number of the form 4k + 3.

(b) Show that the product of any two numbers of the form 4k + 1 is also a number of form 4k + 1.

(c) Now, let us prove proposition 2 by the way of contradiction. Assume, for the sake of contradic- tion, that there is a finite number, say n, such that the list p1, p2, . . . , pn contains all the primes of the form 4k + 3, where k ≥ 0 is an integer. Use parts (a) and (b) to get a contradiction. (Hint: what can you say about the prime factors of [4 (p1p2 · · · pn) − 1]?)

This is what I have. I'm not sure if my b would be correct though.

a) Assume (ad absurdum) that there are only finitely many primes p_1, ..., p_n that are of the form 4k+3. Let N = 4·(p_1)·...·(p_n) − 1. Then N is of the form 4k+3.

b) Observe that the product of numbers that are all of the form 4k+1 must likewise be of the form 4k+1. Consequently N cannot be factored into primes that are all of the form 4k+1 (for then N would also have to be of the form 4k+1).

c) It follows that N is divisible by some prime P of the form 4+3k. On the other hand p_1, ..., p_n are all factors of N+1; so none of them are factors of N. Therefore P is not among them. This contradicts the assumption that {p_1, ..., p_n} is the complete set of primes of the form 4k+3, q.e.d.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! We use Mathjax here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference :)

Answer (score 1):

c is fine. a may need a little more justification (e.g. you can just write down $k$).

For b there is probably not enough justification, although what you say is true. To justify, consider what happens when you multiply two numbers that are of the form $4k + 1$:
$$
(4k + 1)(4k' + 1) = ... ?
$$